# overflow-x not working in dynamically generated DIV in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi guys i am new to jquery and i have two doubts to ask from my coding..

here is my XHTML coding along with my JQUERY and CSS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
       xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
        <style>           
            #filterpanel{
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                left: 0;
                width: 99%;
                height: 20%;
                background-color: azure;
                border: 4px solid black;
                border-radius: 12px;
                overflow-x: scroll;    
           }
        </style>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <div id="filterpanel"></div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){

                for (var i = 0; i &lt; 6; i++) {     

                    var s=$('<div id="filterinfo'+i+'" ><div id="imgclose'+i+'" style="position: absolute; right:0;top: 0;cursor: pointer;" ><img src="images/close.png" width="20px" height="20px"/></div></div>').css({"text-align":"center","background-color":"black","color":"white","position":"relative","width":"16%","height":"98%", "border-radius":"16px","top":"1%","float":"left","left":"0.5%","margin-left":"1%"});
                   s.appendTo("#filterpanel");  
                   $("imgclose"+i).click(function(){
                       alert("clicked");
                       $("filterinfo"+i).hide();
                   });
               }

           });
        </script>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

The thing is all my div's are generated successfully with particular id's as i require ,but what happens is if my value goes above 5 for i , the generated div (i.e) filterinfo6 gets displayed below filterinfo1 instead of right side of filterinfo5 in my main div filterpanel, though i have given overflow-x as scroll for the main div.

My second doubt is that when i click on the imgclose div, the click function does not work ... i really need to close the particular div (i.e) if user clicks on the imgclose4 then the particular div filterinfo4 should be removed from my main div filterpanel .... so far what i have tried is not working .... can anyone help me with this please .

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3XwpG/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3XwpG/

Comment: @VijayakumarSelvaraj thanks for the fiddle bro makes it easier for them to understand what i am trying to convey...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing is change css of `filterinfo` to:

```
{
    "text-align": "center",
    "background-color": "black",
    "color": "white",
    "display": "inline-block",
    "width": "16%",
    "height": "98%",
    "border-radius": "16px",
    "margin-left": "1%"
}
```

The second thing is you must define the height of `#filterpanel` and make `white-space: nowrap`.

```
#filterpanel{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    width: 99%;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: azure;
    border: 4px solid black;
    border-radius: 12px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bobkhin/KaLU8/)

Comment: Your fiddle is linking to the original, unchanged code. Did you forget to press Update?

Comment: In my experience, white-space: nowrap is not required, only specifying height. If you use white-space: nowrap, any text inside the div will not automatically break line when it's longer than the div's width, which is most of the times undesirable.

Answer (score 1):

As we discussed in the chat, you should add `white-space: nowrap;` to the parent div. You are probably also looking for an outcome with `overflow-y: hidden;`

Finally, you should avoid using inline CSS. See my fiddle below for a "clean" version.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3XwpG/9/